# Visual Studio 2010 document map extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Have not seen an extension to Visual Studio 2010, which makes document map like this (on the right side):

[image]

Is there extension for Visual Studio 2010 that makes document map?

Comment: Sorry, my English not very well. I mean: Is there extension for Visual Studio 2010 that makes document map?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=VSIDE) (VS2010 Extension from Microsoft) has what's called Enhanced Scroll Bar. With three modes. The mode you want is full map mode

Once installed:
Tools -> Options... -> Productivity Power Tools -> Enhanced Scroll Bar -> Full map mode

Comment: There is also a 2012 version for VS2012, which is linked from the above version.